# How can I make a geany .tags file for a C++ library?

Tags: configuration, c++, geany

I would like to have auto-completion on the geany text editor (no, it's not an IDE) and for that you use .tags files. There's a plugin that creates .tags files for your programs, but I need to make one for an external C++ library (SFML, more specifically). The goal is to have geany display all the possible classes when I type "sf::" and show the methods of said classes when I type those. This would be a huge deal because I could learn SFML much faster this way, without having to search things so much. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution. After searching a bit through my folders and reading some geany documentation, I could figure out the following steps to create a library's .tags file.

- Go to /usr/include/ and search for the library. In my case, it was SFML so I found the folder SFML and in there I saw all the files related to it.
- Do `pkg-config --list-all | grep <library name>`. This will let you see how the library is referenced in pkg-config. I searched for "sfml" and found that to include all modules, I should use "sfml-all".
- With the information you collected, run the following command to create the .tags file replacing where needed `` CFLAGS=`pkg-config --cflags <pkg library name>` geany -gP path/to/save/tagfile/something.cpp.tags path/to/library/headers ``

This should create the tags file. Then you should import it to geany by saving it in $HOME/.config/geany/tags or by importing it via GUI with Tools->Load tags file.

Here is the command I used for SFML, as an example:

```
CFLAGS=`pkg-config --cflags sfml-all` geany -gP /home/username/sfml.cpp.tags /usr/include/SFML/*/*.hpp
```

See how at the end I included all folders in "SFML" with *, and then included all header files by using the wildcard to specify all files that end in .hpp